# Counting data in boolean array

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array, boolean

I have an array declared as Dim BList(6, 6) As Boolean which starts with the default of false and changes to true when something happens etc.

So want i want to do is count how of (1, 1-6) are set true. But i want to do it for (2, 1-6) as well and so forth until it gets to (6, 1-6). Each level will be stored in a separate var.'

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I know i need to use code such as this [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eefw3xsy(v=vs.100).aspx) but im not sure to change it to only check (1,1-6)

Comment: Edit: To better explain what i need help with
 If (BList(1, 1) = True) Then

End If

This code above is work for what i need it for but it requests me to repeat it 6 times to check the whole blist(1). How could it be done so it checks Blist(1,1 to 6)

Comment: Read up on using loops: For i=1 to 6 ... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else wants to know how i solved this

```
 For aa = 1 To 6
        If BList(aa, 6) = True Then
            level6 += 1
        End If
    Next aa
```